# What Type Of Protein Is Best For You?

Tags: protein, protein-shakes, whey

how is whey made, the different types of whey protein and how much whey protein should we supplement with.

Comment: Whey protein is useless, you get enough of all proteins needed from eating normal food in normal quantities.  If you still need an edge then creatine and beta alanine are the only worth buying. Buy them in a pharmacy. Other good supplements are simply minerals and omega-3, everything else is worthless and potentially harmful

Comment: How was this question listed as "too broad"? Jesus people.

Answer (score 5):

Whey protein and casein are [actually by-products of making cheese](https://us.myprotein.com/thezone/supplements/how-is-whey-protein-made/). They are separated during the cheese making process. Cheese manufacturers will sell this excess whey to supplements companies who then turn around and process it further.  They remove the remaining fats, lactose, dry it, and then flavor it.

There are three types of whey that are mostly how much processing is done.  The differences between them are how much lactose, fats, and carbs are in them.

**Whey concentrate** is the cheapest and most common form.  It is also the least pure protein supplement.

**Whey protein isolate** is a more heavily processed form of whey. Almost entirely protein. Most of the fats and lactose have been removed (though some always remain).

**Hydrolyzed Whey protein** is whey protein isolate, but the protein chains have been broken down in to smaller strands. These make it faster absorption (though the jury is still out on whether this is actually helpful).

There are of course dozens of other protein powder supplements. Whey is just one of the cheapest. Casein is another popular style which is very slow absorption in comparison to whey. There is also supplements made out of peas, hemp, eggs, brown rice, mixed plants and probably more.

How much do you need? Absolutely none at all if you're eating enough in your diet. [The general rule of thumb is you should aim for about 0.8g - 1 gram of protein for every pound of lean body mass or 1.7g - 2.2g per kilogram](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28179492). There's nothing really special about protein supplementation other than being marketed really well. It is also just really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have found that BEEF PROTEIN works better for me. My body just seems to respond better to it than it does to MILK PROTEIN.

I buy cheap jerky to nibble on at my desk:

[image: Jack Link's Jerky]

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VB1XXVU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VB1XXVU)

1-oz has 11 grams of protein, so I usually have 2-oz (still small enough quantity to fit into your hand). You can even carry jerky around in your pocket if you are in a pinch. It's not the most sanitary, but it won't really hurt anything.

After workouts, instead of having the traditional whey protein shake, I have been using this BEEF PROTEIN for the last 6-months:

[image: Carnivor Chocolate Peanut Butter]

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NVJE7HY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NVJE7HY)

(FYI: The peanut butter / chocolate flavor linked above seems to taste the best to me - but none of the BEEF PROTEIN drinks seem to taste as "yummy" as MILK PROTEIN)

I can honestly say that I feel more pumped in the gym, I have gotten leaner, and people at the gym are asking me what I'm doing to put on size. I tell everyone it is this BEEF PROTEIN, but I don't think I am making any converts. I think it has something to do with the fact that BEEF PROTEIN naturally has Creatine in it.

I was remarking about this at the gym, and one of the trainers pointed out to me that all MILK PROTEIN contains estrogen*. It was further explained to me that if you want to build muscle and get stronger, you do not want to be pumping estrogen into your system.

*Estrogen is the primary female sex hormone. It is responsible for the development and regulation of the female reproductive system and secondary sex characteristics. 
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrogen

(NOTE: Amazon links are small, and they have low prices)

Comment: All animal tissues and liquids have hormones in them... if you happen to eat a female animal its filled with estrogen obviously.

Comment: @Ekaen, I don't believe a slab of beef still caries the estrogen that whey protein does. Otherwise, you would see places marketing them as bull steaks or cow steaks.